# Форма и обработчик на одной странице!

Tags: html, php

Пишу форму и обработчик на одной странице - сначало идет проверка запущенна ли форма? такая

```
if (isset ($POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'submit') {echo ",skjdsd!";}
```

потом идет сама форма

```
<form action='coalition.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<label><h3>Новости</h3></label>
<br>
<textarea cols='45' rows='4' name='text'></textarea><br>
<input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[login]'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$myrow[id]'>
<input type="FILE"      name="uploadfile">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
но изначальня проверка нчего не выдает хотя по идее функция Эхо должно сигнализировать нам об начале отправки данных!! не могу разобратья поечему?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты делай лучше так:

```
if(count($_POST)>0){/*code*/}
```

или

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){/*code*/}
```

Вот и все пожалуй. Сам использую такую схему.

Comment: а как вы предотвращаете появление для пользователей окна "Подтвердите повторную отправку формы"?

Comment: достаточно просто обновить страницу.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
/*обработка...и если все прошло успешно, то:*/
header('Location: http://адрес_на_который_хочу')
}

Comment: Пояснить подробней?

Comment: да пожалуйста это что то вроде 

    <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; URL=my_coalitions.php'> ??

Comment: да. советую познакомиться с функцией header (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php). Браузер требует повторную отправку формы при обновлении по причине того, что массив POST не пустой. после обновления, массив POST автоматически удалится.

Answer (score 0):

Поле submit в форме имеет значение "Отправить", а не submit.

Comment: заменил на 


    if (isset ($POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] ==  "Отправить") {echo ",skjdsdsdsdsdffffffffffffffffffffsfsdsdsdsdsd!";}

все равно не помогает(

Comment: var_dump($_POST); вначале скрипта поможет. Но лучше конечно использовать Debugger какой-нить

Comment: да выводит массив но мне надо вместо Эхо вставить скрипт обработчика формы что бы он запусклся после инициализации субмита но этот иссет по прежнему не работает(

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что var_dump поможет Вам понять, чему равен $_POST['submit'] и есть ли он там вообще и поправить условие, таким образом.